# Questions from Miles Reid's undergraduate Algebraic Geometry.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am currently reading through Miles Reid's UG and there are a few statements which I do not quite understand.

Pg 9: Given $X^2 + Y^2 = Z^2$ we let $x = X/Z, y = Y/Z$. I understand that there is a parametrization $x = \frac{2\lambda}{\lambda^2 + 1}, y = \frac{\lambda^2 - 1}{\lambda^2 + 1}$ for the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ but I do not see how he arrives to conclusion that "so this gives all solutions $X = 2lm, Y = l^2 - m^2, Z = l^2 + m^2$ where $l, m$ are coprime." Where do the $l, m$ come from?

Pg 13: We define a projective transformation ($T(X)$) of $P^2_R$ as $T(X) = MX$ where $M$ is an invertible $3 x 3$ matrix. The book proceeds by saying "It's easy to understand the effect of this transformation on the affine piece $R^2 \subset P^2_R$ as $(x,y) \rightarrow (A(x,y) + B)/(cx + dy + e)$ where $A$ is $2 x 2$ matrix on top left of M, $B$ is $2 x 1$ on top right and bottom row of M is $(c,d,e)$". I figured the numerator is the Affine transformation but I am not sure where the modding by $cx + dy + e$ comes from.

Comment: Write $\lambda=l/m$ and expand out $x^2+y^2=1$ with the given data.

Comment: Please ask separate questions in separate threads.